# How do I get the dependencies for the pgfSweave package (e.g. a current PGF) in MikTeX?

Tags: r, latex, sweave, miktex

I installed the `pgfSweave` package for color syntax in LaTeX documents, but I ran aground when it comes to a LaTeX dependency. I've installed the `pgf` package via MikTeX's `Package Manager (Admin)` and *believe* to be up to date (I've looked around in the package folder in my MiKTeX install folder, but I have not seen any version numbers). What am I missing?

```
> library(pgfSweave)
Loading required package: stashR
Loading required package: filehash
filehash: Simple key-value database (2.1-1 2010-10-04)
A Set of Tools for Administering SHared Repositories (0.3-3 2009-03-26)
Loading required package: highlight
Loading required package: tools
Loading required package: codetools
Loading required package: parser
Loading required package: Rcpp
Loading required package: optparse
Loading required package: getopt
Loading required package: formatR
tikzDevice: A Device for R Graphics Output in PGF/TikZ Format (v0.5.3)
Checking for a LaTeX compiler...


A working LaTeX compiler was found by checking:
    The PATH using the command pdflatex

Global option tikzLatex set to:
    C:\PROGRA~2\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe

MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.4052 (1.40.11) (MiKTeX 2.9)
Copyright (C) 1982 D. E. Knuth, (C) 1996-2006 Han The Thanh


Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pgfSweave', details:
  call: requirePGFVersion("2.10")
  error: PGF >= 2.10 is required to use pgfSweave
In addition: Warning message:
running command 'C:\PROGRA~2\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe -interaction=batchmode -output-directory C:\Users\romunov\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmply4jAb test-for-pgf.tex' had status 1 
Error: package/namespace load failed for 'pgfSweave'
```

Comment: Q: What am I missing?
A: Linux.
=)

Comment: Do you dare to write that as an answer? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On MikTex repositories, the used version is apparently 2.00. The latest version 2.10 can be downloaded [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/files/). The installation instructions can be find in the manual that is included in the zip file under  `...\pgf_2.10.tds\doc\generic\pgf`.

If you move the complete folder according to the installation instructions. It boils down to copy the relevant gpf folders from the directory structure in the zip file to the directory structure in you miktex installation. Best is to try a TDS-compliant installation, where you replace the `texmf/` in the installation instruction with your miktex installation folder.

Don't forget to refresh the FNDB (filename database) in via the miktex settings app.

Alternatively, you can uninstall the pgf package and place the unzipped directory tree somewhere where Tex can find it. Again, don't forget to refresh the FNDB. Note though that the installed pgf package will have folders in different places of the directory tree of MikTex. So don't just paste everything you find on one folder you find in the directory system.

---

EDIT :

To know the pgf version that is loaded in your tex distribution, try following small document :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfversion
\end{document}
```

Comment: Still no luck. I've tried the "compact" installation in my `/texmf` folder and ran texhash that says that it's skipping the common root folder (I also updated via the MikTex app, under Admin and without, to no avail).

Comment: Also tried TDS-compliant install with no dice. Either I'm doing something wrong or there's something fundamentally broken.

Comment: @Roman : I tried it and got it working. But the funny thing is that I only get a warning, not an error when I load pgfSweave. I run MikTex 2.8, that might make a difference.

Comment: The update solved my problem. I was missing the `xcolor` package. Too bad the error was that my `pgf` package is not up to date, instead of the missing dependency.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik "Either I'm doing something wrong or there's something fundamentally broken." Apparently it was both.